# Mirth Javascript How to set value if received value is in an array

Tags: javascript, transformer-model, mirth

What I need to do is very simple.  I need to set the PV1-2.1 value if the received PV1-18.1 value is in a list of values.  I set my variable to an array of those values but the check doesn't seem to be working

```
var type = ['YB','ES','EO','SO','CX']
if msg['PV1']['PV1.18']['PV1.18.1'] = type {
msg['PV1']['PV1.2']['PV1.2.1'] = 'V';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try writing your condition as:

```
    if(type.includes(msg['PV1']['PV1.18']['PV1.18.1'])){
        msg['PV1']['PV1.2']['PV1.2.1'] = 'V';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try looping through the array and comparing to each element:

```
var type = ['YB','ES','EO','SO','CX'];
var i = type.length();

while (i--){
     if (type[i] == msg['PV1']['PV1.18']['PV1.18.1']){
           msg['PV1']['PV1.2']['PV1.2.1'] = 'V';
     }
}
```